# Show Indicator at last point on Highchart spline chart

Tags: highcharts

I know how to show marker at last point like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4kxmb/).

When the data is dynamic, don't know how to mark the last point.

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal'
        },
        spline: {
          marker: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are adding new points dynamically you can simultaneously remove the marker from the current last point ([`Point.update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update)), while adding a new point with marker enabled ([`Series.addPoint`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint)).

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kxmb/47/)):

```
// get the series
series = $('#container').highcharts().series[0]

// remove marker from last point
series.points[series.points.length-1].update({
    marker: {
        enabled:false
    }
}, false);

// add new point with marker
series.addPoint({
    y: Math.random()*100,
    marker: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

The `false` parameter for the `Point.update` is to prevent redrawing, as you are going to redraw after the `Series.addPoint` anyway, which should save some processing.

Comment: Looks good. But I have one more question. When the data is coming from API, how you will find the last point and mark it @halvorStran

Comment: @Ramesh you get the data, and then what method in Highcharts do you use to insert it into the chart?